# React how can change image certain period?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, software-design

I have a homePage image but ı just want to every 3-4 second image has to be change how can i solve this ?
I dont want to use npm slider etc.

```
 <div className='hero-container'>
      <img src={photo} />
      <div className='slider_text'>
        <Jumbotron text={[ 'WELCOME ' , 'ARE YOU READY ?']} />
      </div>

      <div className='button_position'>
        <div className='hero-btns'>
          <Button className='btns' buttonStyle='btn--outline' buttonSize='btn--large'>
            İLETİŞİM
          </Button>
          <Button className='btns' buttonStyle='btn--primary' buttonSize='btn--large' onClick={console.log('hey')}>
            ÇOK YAKINDA... <i className='far fa-play-circle' />
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
``
```

Comment: You can store the image sources in a cost variable for example **const sources = [...sources]** and a state variable as follows ** const [image,setImage]  = useState(initialImage)** then use the **useEffectHook** to add an interval **useEffect(()=>{ const clearIntervalToken = setInterval(()=>{ setImage(nextImageFromTheArray)},3000 or 4000); return () => clearInterval(clearIntervalToken)**

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of libs that made this. However if you want to do it, I think you could create an effect to mutate your state with a `setInterval`

```
useEffect(()=>{
  setInterval(()=>{
    setImg('img')
  }, 5000);
},[])
```

Something like this